# XMLHttpRequest POST not working?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to post some data to the server but it, returning me status 0, It is only not working on android 4.2.2 as i am working on cordova application. Is the issue of cross domain ? 
I also tried Access-Control-Allow-Origin = * in header and config.xml.

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

if (!method)
    method = "POST";

if (!contentType)
    contentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

req.open(method, url, true);

req.setRequestHeader("Content-type", contentType);
req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json,text/javascript,");

var timeoutHandler = function() {
    //console.log("timeoutHandler: readyState: " + req.readyState);

    if (req.readyState >= 2)
        return;

    if (window.sus)
        window.sus.updateLimitedConn(true);

    if (err)
        err(1001);

    req.abort();
};

var reqTimeoutID = setTimeout(timeoutHandler, 30000);

req.onload = function() {
    //console.log("xhr onload: readyState: " + req.readyState + ", status: " + req.status);

    if (req.readyState != 4)
        return;

    clearTimeout(reqTimeoutID);

    if (req.status == 200) {
        if (window.sus)
            window.sus.updateLimitedConn(false);

        if (suc)
            suc(req.responseText);
    }
    else {
        if (window.sus && (req.status == 408 || (req.status >= 500 && req.status <= 599)))
            window.sus.updateLimitedConn(true);

        if (err)
            err(req.status);
    }
};

req.onerror = function() {
    //console.log("xhr onerror: readyState: " + req.readyState + ", status: " + req.status);
    clearTimeout(reqTimeoutID);
    if (err)
        err(1002);
};

req.send(data);
```

Comment: As cordova is running in a webview, theres no issue with cross domain (as long as you have access origin="*" in config.xml). You say it's only not working in android 4.2.2, you mean it works on other platforms with cordova? Maybe you could log the response you get when it fails?

Comment: It is fixed , i had to call super.init(); 
in my main activity where i was loading the page index.html.
Do not know what was the reason of that.

Answer (score 0):

I think I had a similar problem. Try this:

In your cordova *config.xml* file add:

```
<access origin="*" />
```

In your *AndroidManifest.xml* (platforms/android/) add:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Good luck!

Comment: I added that.It is fixed , i had to call super.init(); in my main activity where i was loading the page index.html. Do not know what was the reason of that.